# Sprite image returns with "image not found" icon in the middle

Tags: css, sprite

I'm using sprite image with 6 different image line up in a row, each pic is 75x75.
When I load the images, they have the "image-not-found" icon in the middle.
here's the code of 2 images:

**CSS**

```
img.freebo {
   width: 75px; height: 75px;
   background: #fff url('../images/teacher-sprite.jpg') 0 0;
   display:block; float: left; margin: 5px;vertical-align:middle;}
img.randall {
   width: 75px; height: 75px;
   background: #fff url('../images/teacher-sprite.jpg') -75px 0;
   display:block; float: left; margin: 5px;vertical-align:middle;}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="freebo" src="teacher-sprite.jpg">
<img class="randall" src="teacher-sprite.jpg">
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried working with absolute path??

Comment: What is your file structure?

Comment: Try checking the file path. Try adding an image from the internet (with a http:// adress) and see if that results anything

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to load the images from the current directory AND from the ../images directory? Because that's what you're trying to do. Display two images on top of each other.

Comment: Here, [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Uj8ja/1/). That is what your icons looks like, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
../images/teacher-sprite.jpg'
```

This path say to browser: send a request to server for image in `#something/images/teacher-sprite.jpg` where `#something` is the same `#something` internet path that contains the folder that contains the (css?) file that i am reading this path

Anyway: if you have `background-image` attribute in `img` tag why you are using `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<img class="freebo" src="teacher-sprite.jpg">
```

make it into:

```
<div class="freebo"></div>
```

And yes please make sure you have the full path correct